# Docker CLI's dynamically updating output not rendering as intended in ConEmu

Tags: command-line, docker, conemu

I'm running this docker command in ConEmu terminal, and I'm getting the following output:

```
>docker-compose up --build
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)   <--\
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)       |
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)       |
[+] Building 0.0s (0/1)       |
[+] Building 0.2s (2/2)       | These lines are supposed to 
[+] Building 0.3s (2/3)       | replace the old ones in-place
[+] Building 0.5s (2/3)       |
[+] Building 0.6s (2/3)       |
[+] Building 0.8s (2/3)       |
[+] Building 1.0s (2/3)       |
[+] Building 1.1s (2/3)       |
[+] Building 1.3s (2/3)       |
[+] Building 1.4s (2/3)       |
[+] Building 1.6s (2/3)       |
[+] Building 1.7s (5/8)   <--/
[+] Building 1.8s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                         0.0s  => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                         0.0s  => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                          0.0s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                            0.0s  => => transferring context: 34B                                                                             0.0s  => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:17                                                   1.5s  => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:17@sha256:3f8047ded7bb8e217a879e2d7aabe23d40ed7f975939a384a0f111cc041  0.0s  => [internal] load build context                                                                            0.0s  => => transferring context: 71B                                                                             0.0s  => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                        0.0s  => CACHED [3/4] COPY package*.json .                                                                        0.0s  => CACHED [4/4] RUN npm install                                                                             0.0s  => exporting to image                                                                                       0.1s  => => exporting layers                                                                                      0.0s  => => writing image sha256:abca816d879343fd4c7f0043929bad1dd6dfe02cd3a7b97516345aead5c58a20                 0.0s  => => naming to docker.io/library/test-app_app                                                              0.0s

[+] Running 1/0
 - Container test-app-app-1  Created                                                                         0.0s Attaching to test-app-app-1
test-app-app-1 exited with code 0
```

The lines marked above are not rendering properly. It's supposed to be a dynamically updating output where those lines should replace the old ones in-place instead of logging each update in new line.

It works as intended in regular cmd.exe.

Is this a problem with ConEmu? I've tested with new clean profile to make sure none of my customizations were coming in the way.

I'm using:

- ConEmu 220308 [64]
- Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
- Windows 10 Pro x64 [Version 10.0.19044.1645]

Comment: Please provide versions of the products

Comment: @Maximus added. ConEmu 220308 [64] & Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086